# PowerBI Waterfall Chart - How to rearrange or sort Breakdown?

Tags: powerbi, dax, waterfall

I'm having problem in sorting my Waterfall chart's breakdown according to my preference. As shown in **Picture A**, I would like to strictly fix the breakdown sorting to (CPot - S1P - S1U - S2 - C - Others)

[**Picture A**] - (https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Hih.png)

**Picture B** is the column I use for my 'Category' (together with my date).

[**Picture B**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rRLu.png)

**Picture C** is the column I use for my 'Breakdown'

[**Picture C**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfQgQ.png)

**Picture D** is a measure I created for my 'Y-axis'

[**Picture D**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7Cvp.png)

I would like to strictly fix the breakdown sorting to (CPot - S1P - S1U - S2 - C - Others)

Comment: Click on `...` at the top right of the visual, then select `Sort axis >`. What does it show in the rollover?